# How do I make it so the text is only added once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#paragraph").on("click", function(event){$("#paragraph").append(' Whoah! I didnt even know I could do that! I am a RAINBOW!')
event.preventDefault();})
```

I tried adding event.preventDefault() simply because I know that has to do with actions being permanent in some way or another. I honestly have no idea what it does. My problem is I want the text to only be added once no matter how many times the paragraph is clicked, currently, it keeps adding the text so that if you keep clicking it the text repeats.

Comment: add a global variable switch it on click and use a if statment

Comment: Where is your html and code that sets the html or text for the paragraph with that id?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't think that was necessary. I'm new here and don't know what the standards are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JQuery has a [`.one(..)`](https://api.jquery.com/one/) event that does exactly what you want. It attaches an event hander that fires only once.

```js
$("#paragraph").one("click", function(event){$("#paragraph").append(' Whoah! I didnt even know I could do that! I am a RAINBOW!')});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="paragraph">I am the paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Is one the same thing as on except that it just runs once? I'm just trying to make sure I fully understand.

Comment: @Wayne Yes, exactly. From [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/one/) "The `.one()` method is identical to `.on()`, except that the handler for a given element and event type is unbound after its first invocation."

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score -1):

Add a global. And you can use `this` to reference your element.

```js
let clicked = false;
$("#paragraph").on("click", function(event) {
  if (!clicked) {
    this.append(' Whoah! I didnt even know I could do that! I am a RAINBOW!');
    clicked = true;
  }
})
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">Click</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```